# `type is not comparable to type` error on switch statement in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-redux

My switch statement worked perfectly until I added the last case **actionTypes.POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS_SUCCESS**.

```
import * as actionTypes from "../action-types/prosessguide-async"
import { ProsessguideAsyncAction } from "../actions/prosessguide-async"
import initialState from "../constants/initial-state"
import { IProsessguideAsyncState } from "../types/prosessguide"

const prosessguideAsyncReducer = (
  state: IProsessguideAsyncState = initialState.prosessguideAsync,
  action: ProsessguideAsyncAction,
): IProsessguideAsyncState => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.REQUEST_PROSESSGUIDE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: undefined,
        error: undefined,
        isFetching: true,
      }
    }
    case actionTypes.RECEIVE_PROSESSGUIDE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.data,
        isFetching: false,
      }
    }
    case actionTypes.FETCH_ERROR_PROSESSGUIDE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.error,
        isFetching: false,
      }
    }
    case actionTypes.POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      }
    }
    case actionTypes.POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        submitted: true
      }
    }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default prosessguideAsyncReducer
```

**src/actions/prosessguide-async.ts**

```
export type ProsessguideAsyncAction =
  IRequestProsessguideAction |
  IReceiveProsessguideAction |
  IPostProsessguideAction |
  IFetchErrorProsessguideAction |
  IPostProsessguideAnswersSuccess
```

**src/actions/prosessguide-async.ts**

```
export interface IPostProsessguideAnswersSuccess {
  type: actionTypes.POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS_SUCCESS
}



Type '"POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS_SUCCESS"' is not comparable to type '"REQUEST_PROSESSGUIDE" | "RECEIVE_PROSESSGUIDE" | "POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS" | "FETCH_ERROR_PROS...'.
```

**Now tsc is returning this error:**

```
src/reducers/prosessguide-async.ts(39,10): error TS2678: 
Type '"POST_PROSESSGUIDE_ANSWERS_SUCCESS"' 
is not comparable to type 
'"REQUEST_PROSESSGUIDE" | "RECEIVE_PROSESSGUIDE" | "FETCH_ERROR_PROSESSGUIDE" | 
"POST_PROSESSGUIDE...'.
```

I'm using tsc version 5.6.0

Comment: Can you paste the entire definition for actionTypes?

Comment: You have to share the entire class, probably something with the return type of this function does not match with all the switch cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I had forgotten to add `IPostProsessguideAnswersSuccess` to the `ProsessguideAsyncAction`interface.

Original post updated with a complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a message:
`XXX is not comparable to type YYY` in reducer's switch,
it turned out that I had to **restart webpack dev-server** because it didn't rebuild the source code for some reason.

My code was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Typescipt + React + Redux

Make sure you have added the **types** in the **actions** before using them in the `reducer switch case`.